# How we can make a zero-diagonal Matrix by a Unitary equivalence transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, linear-transformations, lie-groups

We have a diagonal traceless matrix like the 3rd Pauli matrix,  or Gell-Mann's matrices $\lambda_8$ and $\lambda_3$ in su(3). Now, we want to apply a unitary transformation on them and make them have  a zero-diagonal and non zero-off diagonal elements  somehow, such  that the resulting  matrix is orthogonal to the initial matrix. Is there such a unitary matrix?

$$U\lambda U^\dagger =\lambda^\prime , \qquad 
\operatorname{tr} \lambda^\prime  \lambda=0  ~.$$

Comment: Have you tried mathematical induction?

Comment: no i didn't do it .but i think it can not help to me.ِDoyou  have any idea for ir?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have been doing this for breakfast for SU(2), for [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices), Rotating by $\pi/2$ around the *x*-axis,
$$
U=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( 1\!\!1 + i\sigma_1),
$$
so that 
$$
\frac{1}{2} ( 1\!\!1 + i\sigma_1)  \sigma_3   ( 1\!\!1 - i\sigma_1) =\sigma_2,
$$
with tr$\sigma_2\sigma_3 $=0, of course.

In fact, any group rotation *not* around a Cartan-subalgebra member in general helps to get you there. (That is, avoid rotating $\lambda_3$ around $\lambda_8$.) Special care in the rotation accords to projecting the original direction out.